# footer HTML inside Javascript

Tags: footer, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Hello i'm using the following javascript code which will be in a separate file so that it can be referenced globally across the site.

It allows me to have a global reference for html elements such as footers and menus and include them by id:

```
<body>

<div id="copyright"></div>

<script>
var copyright = document.getElementById("copyright");
copyright.innerHTML = "<p>&copy; Some Company 2013</p>";
</script>

</body>
```

This works ok as long as the javascript is placed at the bottom of the page. I was wondering what i might need to modify to allow me to move the script into the header?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code [on DOM ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery). Not fun without a library like jQuery, but I have to ask why you're doing this at all.

There are far, *far* better ways to reuse HTML: [**templating.**](https://www.google.com/search?q=html%20templating)

---

Okay, so you're using jQuery. Then you can use the usual, pervasive document ready handling:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#copyright').html('<p>&copy; Some Company 2013</p>');
});

// or the short-hand version

$(function ()
{
    $('#copyright').html('<p>&copy; Some Company 2013</p>');
});
```

That said, I **still** recommend templating instead. [You can even do it client-side, with jQuery.](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)

Comment: many thanks. i have used server side includes which work ok as well but i end up with multiple url requests on the same page and thought this way might be simpler as i could include several html elements in one single .js file and then call then by id.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you using `document.getElementById()` instead of `$()`?

Comment: sorry i'm not a developer and my javascript is very basic. will look into using $(). need to do some more research. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: I think i've got it $(".footer").load("footer.htm"). Will try this method. Thank you.